# How to remove the 'Choose an operating system' Windows 8.1 Preview boot screen after upgrading to Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, multi-boot, windows-8.1-preview

It's not terribly bothersome because I managed to set it to auto-boot Windows 8.1 after 3 seconds and I normally don't watch my PC boot up, but still figured I would ask.

How can I get rid of this?

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 5):

I [found this](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2155390/choose-default-operating-system-booting-windows.html) and it worked for me:
1) Press the Windows Key (or Windows key plus 'R')
2) Type **msconfig** then press return (or click Enter)
3) Choose the Boot Tab
4) Delete entries other than the Current OS
5) Restart your machine and it should go straight to correct OS